# Node.js spawn() call not working on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, printing

I need to print a file using the command line. When doing something like

```
rundll32 C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo "d:\Temp\test.jpg" "Canon_CP1000"
```

in CMD manually it works just fine and the image gets printed. However, as soon as I use Nodes "spawn" command to achieve the same behaviour it doesn't do anything.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var cliCmd = spawn('rundll32', [
    'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo "d:\\Temp\\test.jpg" "Canon_CP1000"',
]);
cliCmd.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout', data);
});
cliCmd.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr', data);
});
```

There is also no output in the console at all. Other commands in spawn work (e.g. "ipconfig, ['/all']"). I have also tried to separate the space-separated attributes and placing it in an array slot each. No effect.

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of parameters to pass to span your child process.

```
var cliCmd = spawn('rundll32.exe', [
    'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo',  'd:\\Temp\\test.jpg', 'Canon_CP1000'
]);
```

Also, make sure you have the full name of `rundll32.exe`.  You  might also have to specify its path.

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it working. The solution is neither the ".exe" or the path. It's (as you suggested) the combination of splitting the attributes in array parts AND getting rid of the double quotation marks.